# Hyphen rules: should it be "tracking number" or "tracking-number"?

Tags: hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

In the following sentence:

> Once you have a tracking number for the shipment.

Should it be *tracking number* or *tracking-number*?

---

I read through the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen), but it didn't give a clear answer to the above.

Comment: It's also based on the grammar. For instance, almost everybody says *ice cream*, but when it's used adjectivally, some people (but not all) will hyphenate it: *ice-cream sandwich*.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "rule" about hyphenating compound nouns. Certainly in British English, tooth-paste, machine-gun, hair-cut, to-day, good-bye and full-stop are being edged aside by toothpaste, machine gun, haircut, today, goodbye, and full stop. Hyphenated forms tend to be viewed as old fashioned (or 'old-fashioned'). There is no consistency and dictionaries and style guides often contradict each other. Your Wikipedia page makes this lack of consistency clear:

> When an object is compounded with a verbal noun, such as egg-beater (a
>   tool that beats eggs), the result is **sometimes** hyphenated. **Some
>   authors do this consistently, others only for disambiguation.**

and...

> Connecting hyphens are used in a large number of miscellaneous
>   compounds, other than modifiers, such as in lily-of-the-valley,
>   cock-a-hoop, clever-clever, tittle-tattle and orang-utan. **Use is often
>   dictated by convention rather than fixed rules, and hyphenation styles
>   may vary between authors**; for example, orang-utan is also written as
>   orangutan or orang utan, and lily-of-the-valley may be hyphenated or
>   not.

You should choose a style and stick to it. Consult a dictionary if you are unsure. If the dictionary is unclear, consider a manual of style.

[Hyphenating compound words](https://getitwriteonline.com/articles/compound-words-hyphen/)